# Use drag and drop cursor in other events

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net

During some uses of a program I'm working on, I need to display the drag-and-drop cursor with the little dotted-box with the little plus sign, used when copying something. From within the DragEnter event handler, I can just set e.Effect to DragDropEffects.Copy, but I need to do this same thing elsewhere in the application, where I don't have a DragEventArgs object to work with.

Short of adding a new cursor file to my project and manually creating the graphic that matches Microsoft's cursors, (I'm sure there's some kind of legal issue with doing that) are there any options anywhere in C# or VB that allow me to get that cursor style without the DragEnter event?

Answer (score 1):

For the minimal amount of work, you can use .NET's "SizeAll" cursor.  While I don't think it's exactly the drag-and-drop one you're referring to, it is a universal image to move something in Windows.  To do this in C#, use:

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll;
```

Or in VB .NET, use:

```
Me.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll
```

If that cursor doesn't work for you, here's a link that shows all the available .NET cursors, and their names: [All Cursors on the a Form](http://www.authorcode.com/show-all-cursors/)

Comment: Already looked at everything in the Cursors class, and as you mentioned, none of them are exactly the drag-and-drop cursor, which is what I need.